# How can I change a background image depending on what results are being displayed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, background-image

I have a table of venues and areas where each venue belongs to an area and an area has many venues.

The venues index page is displaying all the venue records as partials and I have a set of checkboxes to filter the venues shown by what area they are in.

I also have a div (map_container) which shows a map .png image of all the areas on the right of the screen.

**venue index.html.erb**

```
<div class="map_container">
</div>

<div class="filter_options_container">
  <form class="form">          
    <fieldset class="filter_form_fieldset areas">
      <% Area.all.each do |a| %>
      <%= check_box_tag 'areas[]', a.id, false, :id => "area-#{a.id}" %>
        <label for="area-<%= a.id %>"><p1><%= a.name %></p1></label>
      <% end %>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="form_filter_button">
      <p2><input type="submit" value="Filter"/></p2>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="venue_partials_container">
  <%= render :partial => 'venue', :collection => @venues %>      
  <div class="clearall"></div>
</div>

<div class="clearall"></div>
```

How would it be possible to check whether all the venues being displayed have the same area_id and if they do display a different map image in the map div? So if all venues have area_id of 1 then display map1.png or if they all have an area_id of 2 then display map2.png etc.

Thanks for any help, its much appreciated!

Comment: it seems to be a job for your controller. Check area_id inside and pass a variable to the view to display the proper pic.

Comment: @apneadiving thanks for having a look, I'm super new to this, do you know of any tutorials or resources I could look at to help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you might want the background image to update dynamically when checkboxes are changed by the user? If so, the best bet is to use CSS to set a background-image URL on map_container, based on some other class:

```
.map_container_map1 {
  background-image: url('/images/map1.png')
}
```

In javascript, attach the class `map_container_map1` if all the checkboxes are set for area 1.

You should write a javascript function that's called on docReady, as well as whenever a checkbox is clicked. Something like this, in jQuery:

```
// docReady
$(function() {
  updateMap();
}

$(document).delegate('checkbox[name|="areas"', 'change', function(event) {
  updateMap();
});

function updateMap() {
  // Loop through all the checkboxes, check their values to see if they're the same
  $('checkbox[name|="areas"').each(function() {
    ...
  });
  var map = $j('.map_container');
  map.removeClass('map_container_area1 map_container_area2');
  if (area1)
    $j('.map_container').addClass('map_container_area1');
  else if (area2)
    $j('.map_container').addClass('map_container_area2');
}
```

This should hopefully get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, its not working yet but I'm gonna try play around and see what comes of it thanks very much!